# Mail OneClick errormessage

Tags: php

I'm developing a site on whichs record are displayed after they are read from a .csv file.
Sometimes fields contain errors, and I would like to display a button/link that automatically sends me an email when a user clicks the button.

Now it works like this:

```
if ($url == null && $naam == null) {
  echo "\n<li><span class=\"naam\">Foute Invoer.</span>\n<br /><span class=\"error\"><a href=\"mailto:myname@institution.be?subject=Fout 0&body=Error 0 - No URL - No Name - File: " . $csv . " Line: " . $line . "\">Fout melden</a></span></li>\n";
}
```

Now the users still have to click send in Outlook/whatever email software they are using, and can edit the message too.

I'd like to have a button that automatically sends an email to me when users see an error.

I tried adding the following form instead of the mailto-link:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Zend foutmelding" />
<input type="hidden" name="button_pressed" value="1" />
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['button_pressed']))
{
$to      = 'myname@institution.be';
$subject = 'Errorcode';
$message = 'File: ' . $csv . ' Line: ' . $line;
$headers = 'From: myname@institution.be';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

echo 'Email Sent.';
}
?>
```

But that way it sends an email for every error on the page (for example, the page I tested it on contained 3 errors, so I got three emails.)

Is there a solution where I only get one email, for the record selected? Because this site will have thousands of records, so I can't receive a thousand emails a day for every error on the site.

**UPDATE + ANSWER**

Though I know this is not the best solution for my problem, I have found a solution for the question I asked first:

I created an id for each record

```
$id = $filter . "_" . $line;
```

Then I changed the form to:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Zend foutmelding" />
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $id; ?>" value="1" />
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST[$id]))
{
$to      = 'myname@institution.be';
$subject = 'Errorcode';
$message = 'File: ' . $csv . ' Line: ' . $line;
$headers = 'From: myname@institution.be';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

echo 'Email Sent.';
}
?>
```

Yes, it works.
Yes, almost to simple to ask here, I know...

Now I will continue to think about more elegant solutions which really solve my problem with error-reporting.

Thanks for helping and thinking along with me.

Comment: exactly why should clicking a button in an error field send you an email? If it's "report this error", you should be doing that when the html page is generated in the first place, when you're parsing the list and can build up one email.

Comment: Good point, but sometimes records have errors that can't be detected automatically (Like wrong URL's, wrong usernames or passwords.)
So it would be easier to have a button per record.
But then again, the automatic mail can't contain the correct record, so perhaps it's better to stick to mailto-links per item, so users can add more info.

Answer (score 0):

You wont come along without logging here.

The best is make a table with errors code and timestamps so every errorcode will be selected, and if not available today recorded and then an E-Mail will be sent.

Without writing down what you already sent it will be very hard to make it work, except going by session or something like that but this is not a very clear solution cause every different use rwill generate an E-Mail again.

Comment: The problem is, I can't really work with logging since I have no database. Also the problem with errors that can't be detected automatically remains.
Thinking about other solutions right now.

Comment: Then it won't be really possible. Well do you have write access to the folder of the website? Then just create a file with a shell command if possible and store your information there, seperated with ; or something and then read the file contents and use explode to fetch your results. Not beautiful but would atleast help...

Comment: I do have write-access, but cannot add cronjobs myself (so the script would need to be run manually).
Other solution I'm thinking right now is:
Auto-detectable errors, like empty fields get a code, every item get's a mailto-link.
If an auto-detectable is present, it is automatically added to the Body, otherwise users can add a message of their own, to notify me of wrong usernames, for example.
At the end, $csv and $line are always included.

Also not the most beautiful solution, but I believe this wil be the most easy solution in the beginning...

Comment: You dont need a cronjob you can call it everytime an error occurs, read file -> search for error id already sent -> if not: write to log file + send email -> done